Rhytmbox "Browse this Artist" doesn't work
For years I've had Rhythmbox, but if I right-click on a song and select Browse this Artist nothing happens. Browse this Genre and Album don't work either.
I've tried this on countless songs. I've updated Rhythmbox, but these features still don't work. When I bought a new computer and installed Ubuntu on it, Rhythmbox still didn't work for these features. My songs all display the artists, genres and albums correctly.
I'm using Ubuntu 24.04 and Rhythmbox 3.4.7.

Welcome to Ask. This works for me. Possibly it appears not to work as the default display already selects 'Artist' and 'Album' along the top so you are probably starting from a selection of a selection. In most cases 'Genre' of an album are all the same so that too. In otherswords you start from a pre-selection, it doesn't work backwards. If you turn off the pre-selection by asserting 'browse' the starting point is all available tracks. Then select by 'Artist', :Album' or 'Genre' and it should cut down the selection as described.
